# In ckeditor how can we avoid extra non-breaking spaces in paragraph tags?

Tags: ckeditor

When editing in ckeditor I very frequently end up with extra clusters of `<p>&nbsp;</p>` tags. Not only does it add extra unneeded linebreaks, they often show up on the resulting page with a broken-looking character in them.

Is there a configuration setting or something to tell the editor not to add these extra non-breaking spaces in paragraph tags?

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 1):

The paragraphs with `&nbsp;` represent empty lines in editor. They make the content look exactly the same inside editor and outside it (when displayed on a target page). If they cause you some problem, then it's not the editor, but your backend. So I rather recommend checking it.

Surprisingly though, there's an option to disable filling empty blocks [`config.fillEmptyBlocks`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-fillEmptyBlocks).

But it's really not the answer.